# How to set the input shape of keras LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I often hit the proglem as

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [10 ,3]`

I googled around  and found out that

`LSTM layer expects inputs to have shape of (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`

OK, but honestly I am still confused a bit.

So for example,I have training data like this

```
x_train (100,3) #it consists of like `[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]]`
y_train (100,3) #answers
```

I want to use 10 set of 3 pair of numbers and predict next 3pair ex `[7,8,9]`.

like guessing from x_train[1~10] to y_train[11]`

The code below works but , I am still not clear

At the place `input_shape=(3,1)` What the meaning of `1`??. it should be `3` (the dimension I want to get finally)

And `batch_size` is the first argument of LSTM requests.

So,,,when I want to predict one from past 10 items, is it correct to set here 10???

```
x_train = np.array(x).reshape(100, 3,1)
y_train = np.array(x).reshape(100, 3,1)

model.add(LSTM(512, activation=None, input_shape=(3, 1), return_sequences=True))

model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear"))

opt = Adam(lr=0.001)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt)
model.summary()
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epoch, batch_size=10) // how to set batch size???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
x = np.random.uniform(0, 10, [101, 3])

x_train = np.array(x[:-1]).reshape(-1, 5, 3) # your data comprise of 20 sequences
y_train = np.array(x[1:]).reshape(-1, 5, 3)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(512, activation=None, input_shape=(None, 3), return_sequences=True))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear"))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt)
model.summary()
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=10) # here you can set a batch size (your 20 sequences will be splitted into two batches)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have clearly found out and confirmed. I need to put dimension here `input_shape=(None, *)`. My first idea was wrong.